# Delete a directory from a script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a ruby script that runs as a daemon process.  After a new record is saved I want to delete all folders and files in the cache directory.  I have tried the code below with no success:

```
 require 'fileutils'

 @report.save
 FileUtils.rm_rf("absolute_path/tmp/cache/.")
 # also tried
 # FileUtils.rm_rf("#{RAILS.root}/tmp/cache/.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FileUtils.rm_rf` doesn't accept wildcards on its own. If you want want keep the cache directory itself, and remove its contents only, use a `glob`:

```
FileUtils.rm_rf Dir.glob('absolute_path/tmp/cache/*')
```